# AppServiceProvider with locale set in controller

Tags: laravel

Here is the situation :

- I'm using Laravel 5.3
- On my `Text` model, I have these two columns : `slug_fr` and `slug_en`
- My router calls `textController`, on which I set the locale (`fr` or `en`), depending on which slug was found (With `App::setLocale()`).
- On my `Text` model, I have this method `getSlugAttribute`, which returns the slug depending on the locale, defaulting to the english one if something is wrong.

All worked perfectly, but I needed to create a menu on all my pages. I updated the `AppServiceProvider:boot()` method to share the menu within all views (As explained [in Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)), creating a simple array for each of my pages (I called `$text->slug` on each of the page here). The array was as follows :

```
$menu[] = [
    'title' => $text->title, // (I also have a getTitleAttribute working the same way)
    'slug' => $text->slug,
];
```

As I soon discovered, the AppServiceProvider is executed before the router and my controller, and my locale isn't set yet resulting on all my menu items being in english (The fallback of my methods).

I updated the serviceProvider to return an array of text objects, so the call to getSlugAttribute is made in the view (And therefore after the locale is set), but I don't find it very neat.

```
$menu[] = $text;
```

Is there a neatier way to do so ? Is my logic completely flawed ? I'm open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use `view()->composer('*')`. Variables there will be shared with all your views. I use it for my navbar.

Something like:

```
//Route file
view()->composer('*', function ($view) {

    //Whatever logic you need to get to your $menu

    return $view->with('menu', $menu)

});
```

You can also define subgroups `view()->composer('foo.*')`.

Comment: Nice, it works perfectly ! i'm just a bit bothered to have it in the route file, but as it works ...

Comment: You can always abstract your logic to a custom service class to keep your routes clean